# Keep flow rate constant from a drip container

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure, everyday-life

I will be using an elevated container attached to tubing with a ball valve on the end to drip a liquid into my saltwater aquarium to help with coral growth.  Conceptually it will be similar to an IV drip but just homemade.  Ideally, I want to keep that rate of flow as constant as possible as the liquid in the container drains over time.  It makes sense to me as the liquid gets lower the flow rate will decrease (at least in the IV type setup).  Another way I could do it is to drip a hole in the top of the container and place the tube so that it creates a siphon.  Would this still be prone to that decrease in flow over time?

Comment: I would recommend siphon technique.

Comment: It'll keep the flow steady

Comment: Siphon flow rate does not remain constant as the water supply lowers.

Comment: @AdrianHoward is it relatively constant or would it slow considerably?

Comment: @Tim The changing flow rate relative to the lowering water level in the container is the equivalent to the changing flow rate from a hole at the bottom of the container. They will slow at about the same rate. I respectfully believe the comments by lee above are incorrect.

Comment: @Tim I am referring to the flow or drip rate when the bottom of the tubes are the same distance below the water level. Whether the water comes through a siphon tube or comes from a tube attached to the bottom of the container the hydrostatic pressure of the water at the bottom valve is governed by gravity alone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to get what you want.

Suspend the reservoir with a spring that pulls the reservoir higher as the liquid drips out of it. By scaling the spring constant and the proportions of the container, you can get the reservoir to rise exactly in lockstep with the drip rate and thereby hold the source pressure for the drip line constant.

Comment: I'm trying to keep this setup as simple as possible.  Do you think the siphon flow will change as the reservoir empties?  To me it seems like this would not be dependent on the pressure of the fluid and would stay relatively constant right?

Comment: that's the idea.